# Why am I not able to add second fragment on top of first?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have fragContainer in activity.
I am able to add the first fragment with following code but the second fragment is not getting added on top of it.

```
fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.add(R.id.fragContainer, fragment)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

I can successfully replace the fragment with `transaction.replace(...)`

Comment: What kind of `ViewGroup` is `fragContainer`? Are you sure you should be expecting it to end up on top? For example, if it's a `LinearLayout` and the first `Fragment` fills it, then the second one will be pushed out the side.

Comment: @MikeM. yes it's LinearLayout. I just changed it to FrameLayout and now it worked. Thanks. But I thought as LinearLayout is also a ViewGroup it should work.

Comment: No problem. It does work, actually, but maybe not like you're thinking. `Fragment`s are really just adding regular `View`s to regular `ViewGroup`s, and those `ViewGroup`s still behave like they would normally. `LinearLayout` does not overlap its children; they're always laid out end to end, no matter if they come from a `Fragment` or not. If you should want to add multiple `Fragment`s into a `LinearLayout`, you certainly can: just make sure that they're not `match_parent`. However, they will be laid out linearly, not one atop another.

Comment: I added scrollView to LinearLayout and new fragments are getting added like adding new views dynamically, as the orientation specified in LinearLayout.